# Finding max value

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Which approach would be the best to take in order to calculate the max value of $a$, where $a\ \log(x+1)$ (blue) at no point exceeds $\sqrt{x}$ (red)?

[image]

Comment: You can use a backslash before common functions to get the correct font.  \log gives $\log$, for example.  Thank you for using $\LaTeX$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to find the maximum value of $\frac {\log (x+1)}{\sqrt x}$ so take the derivative and set to zero.  You get an expression that cannot (without the Lambert W function) be solved analytically.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20derivative%20of%20%20log%28x%2b1%29/sqrt%28x%29=0) gets about $x=3.92155$ [where](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%284.92155%29/sqrt%283.92155%29) $\frac {\log(x+1)}{\sqrt x}\approx 0.804742$  The maximum $a$ is the inverse of this, about $1.24263$

Comment: Many thanks for your reply - the problem I am working on is actually a little more complex, though essentially the same prnciple - should I post as a separate question?

Comment: If you take the solve and =0 off the first Alpha link, you get [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of++log%28x%2B1%29%2Fsqrt%28x%29) $\frac {\frac{2x}{x+1}-\log(x+1)}{2x^{3/2}}$  Yes, if you have a different question I would post it separately

Comment: Great - thank you very much :)